# two dimensions brush in d3 v4

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, npm

I have a problem with converting d3 v3 to d3 v4

I have this code :

```
  var brush = d3.svg.brush()
      .x(x)
      .y(y)
      .on("brushstart", brushstart)
      .on("brush", brushmove)
      .on("brushend", brushend);
```

but I don't know how to write it in v4

I tried

```
 var brush = d3.brush()
      .brushX(x)
      .brushY(y)
      .on("brushstart", brushstart)
      .on("brush", brushmove)
      .on("brushend", brushend);
```

but it doesn't work
[image]

NB: Im using the package npm:  "d3-brush": "^1.0.4",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the correct behavior. Reading the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/blob/master/README.md#brush), one notices, that `d3.brush()` on its own will do the job of creating a two-dimensional brush:

> [#](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/blob/master/README.md#brush) d3.**brush**() [<>](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/blob/master/src/brush.js#L131)
>
> Creates a new two-dimensional brush.

Hence, there are no methods `brush.brushX()` nor `brush.brushY()` on the created brush. The methods [`d3.brushX()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/blob/master/README.md#brushX) and [`d3.brushY()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/blob/master/README.md#brushY) would create a one-dimensional brush instead.

Therefore, your code would end up like the following:

```
var brush = d3.brush()
  .on("start", brushstart)
  .on("brush", brushmove)
  .on("end", brushend);
```

Comment: but how can i define the scales ( x,y :scaleLinear) in brush; (I tried your solution and I received Uncaught Error: unknown type: brushstart)

Comment: @MrGildarts The handling of brushes has changed from v3 to v4. The new version's brushes no longer depend on scales (see [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/blob/master/README.md) for details). As for the *unknown type* error: have a look at my recent edit! The names of the event types have also changed: `"brushstart"` ↦ `"start"`,  `"brushend"` ↦ `"end"`. If you have any problems regarding these issues, I suggest you post a new question instead.

Comment: thnx, but Im not sure if its working, this time I recevied the error d3.js:4100 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseVal' of undefined, he had a pb with cell.call(brush); instruction

Comment: @MrGildarts Like I said, these are follow-up problems, which should be posted as another question. When doing so, please provide a [mcve] to demonstrate your issues for others to be able to help.